# Is there a class method or command to view the globals in .gof files? and how to extract the specific global within gof files

Tags: caching, global, intersystems

I want to get one global within .gof files, such as there is a file named export.gof(contains ^a,^b,^c),but i just want to get ^b, so how could i get that specific global with a command or classmethod. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Class `%Global` has method [Import](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Library.Global#METHOD_Import) with GlobalList as the second argument, so, you can choose which globals to import or all. But, unfortunately, this argument ignored for `GOF` files. So, looks like, the only way is to import to another namespace or database (CACHETEMP for example), and merge particular global to the desired destination.